# Export Files from OpenVZ root.hdd

Tags: linux, debian, mount, backup, openvz

I have a little problem, and I have had a backup from my hoster, this consists of the following files, now the question arises how do I get the files out of it, I don't want to start servers but those Get files from it
[image]

I hope I am right here with my problem

Comment: I'm guessing that `root.hdd` is a VM disk image.  You could try mounting it on your host system, you could create a new VM and mount this disk image on that new VM.  Which hypervisor are you using?  What is your host system?

Answer (score 0):

That appears to be a [`ploop`](https://github.com/OpenVZ/ploop) image.

You tagged your question Debian, I believe `ploop` is available and `apt install ploop` should work.  Then you should be able to mount/unmount the image using the `ploop` tools:

`ploop mount -m /mnt /path/to/DiskDescriptor.xml`

`ploop umount /path/to/DiskDescriptor.xml`

Comment: Thanks, but I get the following error

Opening delta /home/old/root.hdd/root.hdd
Reopen rw /home/old/root.hdd/root.hdd
Trimming tail
Error in ploop_check (check.c:574): Dirty flag is set
Error in ploop_getdevice (ploop.c:870): Can't open /proc/vz/ploop_minor: No such file or directory

Comment: I have not used ploop through Debian, but I believe there is a kernel module that would need to be loaded.  Does `modprobe ploop` give any errors?  Does the mount work after the module is loaded?

Comment: Yes he show me that Error

modprobe: FATAL: Module ploop not found in directory /lib/modules/5.4.77

Comment: I am not sure, but maybe `ploop` is only available in OpenVZ's own custom kernel (odd that it is packaged for Debian in a non-working state).  You could setup an [OpenVZ](https://download.openvz.org/virtuozzo/releases/7.0/x86_64/iso/openvz-iso-7.0.15.iso) virtual machine and try to extract your image using that.